# TypeError: Cannot read property '$data' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am facing this issue when trying to use the ng-repeat to populate the data to the editable table data.

Below is my updated code:

```
 <table>
 <tr style="white-space: nowrap">
   <td ng-repeat="assignment in vm.assignments" class="text-center">
                 <span>
                     {{ assignment.name }}
                     &nbsp;
                 </span>
                  <form editable-form name="{{assignment.name}}" ng-show="{{assignment.name}}.$visible">
                         <button type="submit" ng-disabled="{{assignment.name}}.$waiting">
                             save
                         </button>
                         <button type="button" ng-disabled="{{assignment.name}}.$waiting" 
                             ng-click="$eval(assignment.name).$cancel()">
                             cancel
                         </button>
                     </form>
                     <a ng-show="!{{assignment.name}}.$visible" ng-click="$eval(assignment.name).$show()">
                         edit
                     </a>
             </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="assignment in vm.assignments">
    <td ng-repeat="grade in assignment.grades" class="text-center">
        <span editable-text="grade.score" e-name="{{ grade.aname }}" e-form="{{grade.aname}}">
            {{ grade.score || '-' }}
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

JS

```
  Assignment.GetAssignmentsByClassId(classId).then(function (data) {
            vm.assignments = data;
            vm.givenAssignments = _.filter(vm.assignments, { 'given': true });
  });
```

Rendered HTML

```
   <span editable-text="grade.score" e-name="research" e-form="research" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable">
            90
       </span>
```

Comment: Could you post your js so we can analyze it better?

Comment: @inafalcao, my JS for this part is fairly simple, just get the data from the web api, then get all the given assignments.

Comment: Is 'data' populated when the response arrives? There is an close parenthesis ); missing from your then(). You could also put the error case: then(function successCallback(data) { }, function errorCallback(response) { }); and debug to see if it is falling on the error case.

Comment: Have you also checked if classId is populated?

Comment: @inafalcao, thanks for your reply. I have corrected the missing close parenthesis. I am pretty confident that the response arrived before the data being populated. The code editable-text="grade.score" cannot rendered, but I am not sure why. Please see the latest update.

Comment: I'm not sure how this editable-text directive is supposed to work but could it be that it expects to get the string of `grade.score`? You're providing `grade.score` not `{{grade.score}}`.

Comment: @MosheYakov, I am providing the grade.score as what described on the xeditable documentation. If I pass {{ grade.score }}, it will prompt an error.

Comment: Is your html wrapped in a `<form>`? If not, try to remove the e-name directive.

Comment: @MosheYakov, I did want to use the form to edit the data. You can look at this xeditable documentation http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-column

Comment: the issue might be due to dynamically assigned e-form value, anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think the problem is with the e-forms not marching any of your forms in the first ng-repeat. The forms are assigned names of assignment.name and then for each assignment you're repeating its grades and assigning grade.aname to e-form.... while there are no forms with those names.

Comment: @MosheYakov, the assignmed names of assignment.uname and grade.aname are the same value. I have figured out that the issue was due to two different ng-repeat. Thanks for your help.